# Search paths for DTLloaddb from datatool

Tags: datatool

I have a couple of CSV files I read via `DTLloaddb`. And these files are scattered over multiple folders. 
So far, `DTLloaddb` seems to require a direct (absolute or relative) path to the filename. Is there any have here something like `graphicspath` for datatool data bases?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{filecontents*}{someremotedir/data.csv}
    x y
    1 2
    3 4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \DTLloaddb[noheader=false]{coordinates1}{data.csv}
\end{document}
```